# SQLite backend does not support timezone-aware times even if USE_TZ = True

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am now developping a small django projects which needs to work with aware datetime.time objects.

When the user registers, he has to fill a time input. This data is then transformed to an aware time object in my views.py file just like that:

```
...
if form.cleaned_data['reviews_time']:
    form.cleaned_data['reviews_time'] = form.cleaned_data['reviews_time'].replace(tzinfo=get_current_timezone())
else:
    form.cleaned_data['reviews_time'] = time(hour=0,minute=0,tzinfo=get_current_timezone())

*save the created user account*
...
```

The problem is that when I submitt the form, I get the following error : `SQLite backend does not support timezone-aware times.`
Even if I have USE_TZ enabled.

I would like to know why this error happens and how to fix it. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful (and feel free to ask for extra code/explanations)`enter code here`

Comment: See [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32513?cversion=0&cnum_hist=8) django issue

Comment: Django's timezone functionality applies to `DateTimeField`, not `TimeField`.

Comment: Oh yes my bad, thanks for the rectification !

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, USE_TZ was set to False. After changing it to
USE_TZ = True
everything is working fine.